# AWS upload folders and their contents to s3 under separate keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to upload to s3 an folder with the following structure : my-folder/sub-folder/file.json, my problem is that i want to have separate keys at each step, i want to have a key for my-folder/ and key for my-folder/sub-folder/ and a key for my-folder/sub-folder/file.json, but when i do it from aws cli with the following command "aws s3 cp local_path s3://my_bucket --recursive" everything is uploaded under a single key, more specific under my_folder/sub_folder/file.json, is there a way to achive what i'm trying here ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. You need custom solution for that.

Comment: What is the directory structure of `local_path` ?

Comment: The --recursive flag will do nothing if you are uploading a single file.

Answer (score 0):

The file/folder structure in a given s3 bucket is actually always flat but we add slashes into keys for clarifying a pseudo hierarchy for organizational purposes.  This means that in your example, you cannot make keys for the intermediary files in `my-folder/sub-folder/file.json`, however they *will* show up as "files" in the aws web console. The only way to get the desired effect where they are actually unique keys would be in theory (though not sure, since this is a bad practice) storing one thing at `my-folder/sub-folder/file.json` and something entirely different at `my-folder/subfolder` because as I explained before, the directory structure is only implied by the slashes, but not enforced by any underlying data structure.  That said, you should probably not do this. What is your use case?